# Interesting situation with background

Tags: html, css, background

I have an interesting situation, that I can't understand how resolve it.

[image]

I need something like this,

this is an example, the background in `html` is repeating, then we have wrapper, with fixed size centered horizontly, but in which I must see the background, but in this case not with light overlay (or opacity if you want), the images must match, , can anyone help me with this?

Here what I did  http://jsfiddle.net/WfhHE/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An even easier solution will be to set the background position to `center 50px`. Because your inner div starts at 50px from the top and has exactly the width of 5 times the background pattern the following should be almost perfect: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfhHE/18/))

```
html {
height: 1000px;
/* Note the following change */
background: #fff url(http://lh3.ggpht.com/-6jQdie_mJCE/UeV2RpGb87I/AAAAAAAAAJo/PDZsV3baNwU/s0/bg.jpg) center 50px repeat;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the overlaid image, either:

- Use a plain translucent colour as the background (with [rgba and/or images](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/)) to tint the image behind it *or*
- Use a `background-attachment: fixed` background image

Comment: I'm sorry  I didn't understand your answer, I know about alpha channel but  how it can help in this situation

Comment: I check, you were right, the position fixed resolve it, thanks!